# How to change google analytics data granularity programatically through API

Tags: google-analytics

I am pulling data programmatically from google analytics.  This is the query I execute

```
  def executeDataQuery(analytics: Analytics, profileId: String) : GaData = {
    analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId,
      "2012-01-01", // Start date.
      "2012-01-14", // End date.
      "ga:visits") // Metrics.
      .setDimensions("ga:date")
      .setSort("ga:date")    
      .setMaxResults(25)     
      .execute()
  }
```

This gives visits/day. I assume the default granularity is per day.

**How can I change the granularity of the data from visits/day to visits/minute or visits/month?**
I know this can be done on the google analytics website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you can slice up your data using the [Core Reporting API Time - Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time).

For instance, if you wanted to change it to hour, you could do:

```
.setDimensions("ga:dateHour")
```

If you'd like to preview the data that the api can get you, use the [GA Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).

Comment: I've searched all over the web and could not find this link. Thanks!